# External HD Accidentally pulled out of computer

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

A few days ago I accidentally pulled my WD MyBook 1110 Media external HD out of the USB connection on my Macbook Pro.

I have tried to repair the HD with Disk Utility, but the 'Repair Disk' option is grayed out.

Of course I would like to recover the information on the external HD. Is there any way to do this?

When plugged in, the HD starts up perfectly fine and seems to run (I can hear it). But my computer isn't able to recognize it. The message I get is "The disk you inserted was not recognizable on your computer."

I am running Mac Yosemite 10.10 on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Try the steps listed [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63155/54484).

Comment: what does it looks like in your About This Mac? does it show the HDD and what driver is it using?

Comment: Try with resting your PRAM.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I have just encountered the problem yesterday when I accidentally knocked my external drive USB cord off.  I ended up with the same problem in this post.  What I did was connecting the drive to a windows machine and it will automatically detect and fix the errors.  It's an annoying solution but it worked.  I just wish Apple will have some kind of safeguard procedure against things like this from occurring, especially with most people backing up their life onto an external drive.